# Foursquare API: suggestcompletion near specified city

Tags: foursquare

My aim is to find venues in specific city.

For this purpose i am using `/v2/venues/suggestcompletion` endpoint. So for example next request `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/suggestcompletion/?limit=10&query=McDonald&near=Napa,%20CA,%20United%20States&client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy&v=20161118&locale=en` returns venues not only in Napa, but also in Fairfield, Vallejo etc. [Result for this query](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a22f71a344f1d16d4156c0205763f6a2).

Ok, as far as I know what city I need I can filter result by city on my side. But in this approach I received next problem. Next query `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/suggestcompletion/?limit=10&query=Diviera%20Drive&near=New%20York,%20NY,%20United%20States&client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy&v=20161118&locale=en` returns venue in city labeled Brooklyn. [Result for this](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a22f71a344f1d16d4156c02057e3bd3f) Obviously `New York` string and `Brooklyn` does not match. Maybe somehow I can retrieve main city (New York) next to borough (Brooklyn) so I can filter it on my side properly

So my question is: how can I receives venues only in specified city.

Answer (score 0):

The `near` parameter you're using is not a filter - it's a coarse geocoder that's used to generate a latitude/longitude to search near.

The [search documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) does not show a way to limit results to a city name. If you only want to show results in a certain city you'd have to do that filtering yourself. Since the city name may be missing or incorrect (sometimes city boundaries are fuzzy) a more precise way could be filter based on the lat/lng coordinate.

Comment: *Radius* parameter misleading me. It says `Limit results to venues within this many meters of the specified location. Defaults to a city-wide area.`

Comment: What is misleading about `radius`? It limits results to venues within that circle.

Comment: It says `Defaults to a city-wide area`, so I thought it limit results to a city area by default. Now I will try to use **sw** and **ne** params for my purpose. But it would be handy to have option for filter by city functionality.